# struct variable cannot access struct members

Tags: c, variables, struct, member

I was working on a a few basic implementations of structures in C. The goal of my program is to access the members of struct using variables instead of pointers.
This is my program:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h>
struct oldvar{
    char name[100];
    int age;
    float height;
};
void main()
{   

    
    struct oldvar DAD;
    printf("\nThe old values are %s\n%d\n\f",DAD.name,DAD.age,DAD.height);
    strcpy("Will Smith",DAD.name);
    DAD.age = 50;
    DAD.height = 170;
    
    printf("The updated values are %s\n%d\n\f",DAD.name,DAD.age,DAD.height);

}
```

On implementing this, I got only the garbage values and no updates :

```
The old values are ⌡o!uC&uⁿ■a
3985408
```

How can I update my structure members using variables?

Comment: wow, neither of GCC or Clang seem to warn about that!

Comment: @ilkkachu it's normal they don't warn, because in C the type of a string literal is a `char[]` and not `const char[]`. This is pretty stupid, but I think they needed to leave it non const for compatibility/portability issues.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, yeah, I figured that might be it. But given how they do warn about other valid but probably mistaken stuff (like `if (x = y)`), I somehow expected them to catch that, too -- it does very likely lead to an immediate crash anyway. Maybe it's just that it's not a very common error.

Comment: Ah, but [there is `-Wwrite-strings`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html)! (Now I can rest in peace tonight.)

Comment: Printing your old values without initializing them is undefined behavior. If there is no 0 byte available just by accident, printing a non-terminated string might make `printf` crawl through the whole memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers, the first argument to `strcpy()` is the *destination*. Plus there were errors in `printf` too. It was supposed to be `%f`, not `\f`

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h>

struct oldvar {
    char name[100];
    int age;
    float height;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct oldvar DAD={"\n",0,0.0};
    strcpy(DAD.name,"will Smith");
    printf("\nThe old values are %s\n%d\n%f", DAD.name, DAD.age, DAD.height);

    DAD.age = 50;
    DAD.height = 170;

    printf("The updated values are %s\n%d\n%f", DAD.name, DAD.age, DAD.height);
}
```

Comment: In an answer you should post properly indented code.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
    strcpy("Will Smith",DAD.name);
```

is wrong.

According to [strcpy(3) - Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html):

> ```
> char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
> ```

The *destination* (where to write the copy) is the first argument and the *source* (what should be copied) is the second argument.

Therefore, the line should be

```
    strcpy(DAD.name,"Will Smith");
```

Also using values of uninitialized non-static local variable invokes *undefined behavior*, allowing anything to happen.

For more safety, you should initialize the variable `DAD` before printing. In other words, the line

```
    struct oldvar DAD;
```

should be (for example)

```
    struct oldvar DAD = {""};
```

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy("Will Smith",DAD.name);` --> `strcpy(DAD.name, "Will Smith");`

strcpy("Will Smith",DAD.name); will copy DAD.name to some constant memory that contain "Will Smith" (Read only memory part).

So that, your program will crash because there is an attempt to write on READ Only Memory part

Comment: An answer should provide at least a short explanation